# Specs: OSGi HTTP Whiteboard and ServletContextHelper

Tags: osgi, pax-web, osgi-http-service

I need some precision about the ServletContextHelper behavior related to the Http Whiteboard Specification when multiple bundle use the same ServletContextHelper

The spec says :

> The Http Whiteboard implementation must create a separate
>   ServletContext instance for each ServletContextHelper service.
>   Whiteboard services can be associated with the Servlet Context Helper
>   by using the osgi.http.whiteboard.context.select property. If this
>   property is not set, the default Servlet Context Helper is used.

If I understand correctly, all Servlet or Filter using the same ServletContextHelper reference are bound to the same 'ServletContext'

Then :

> Some implementations of the ServletContextHelper may be implemented
>   using a Service Factory, for example to provide resources from the
>   associated bundle, as the default implementation does. Therefore the
>   Whiteboard implementation must get the Servlet Context Helper using
>   the Bundle Context of the bundle that registered the Whiteboard
>   service.

So if a bundle A registers a Servlet with the ServletContextHelper X, and the bundle B registers a Filter with the same reference of ServletContextHelper, then the Servlet and Filter are registered to the same ServletContext, but their init methods are called with two different instances of ServletContext (in order to implements the getClassLoader() methods differently) ?

Moreover, what is the behavior of the "default" ServletContextHelper ? is there always a "default" ServletContextHelper registered ? is it shared between bundles or is there only one instance by bundles ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Pax Web 8, where I really want to get the behavior right.

[140.2.7 Relation to the Servlet Container chapter](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#d0e120290) of OSGi CMPN specification shows a picture, where there are actually three *layers* of `javax.servlet.ServletContext` objects:

- the `ServletContext` implementation specific to real Servlet container. In Pax Web it's one of:

  - `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Context`
  - `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext`
  - `io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl`
- the `ServletContext` implementation in 1:1 relation with the `org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper` OSGi service
- the `ServletContext` that's implementing the service-factory contract for each Whiteboard bundle where all but `getClassLoader()` methods delegate to the above SCH and `getClassLoader()` returns `bundle.adapt(BundleWiring.class).getClassLoader()`

The problem is related to the double-responsibility principle assumed with `org.osgi.service.http.context.ServletContextHelper`. It is used both to implement  functional aspects (`handleSecurity()`) and resource-separation aspects (`getResource()`).

So you're right - if Bundle A registers a servlet and Bundle B registers a filter, both will use the same instance of ServletContext (supported by the referenced ServletContextHelper), but their `init()` methods will be provided with different, bundle-specific instance of `ServletContext`.

This is simply implemented by delegation, there are two implementations:

- `org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiServletContext` implements the 1:1 behavior
- `org.ops4j.pax.web.service.spi.servlet.OsgiScopedServletContext` implements `getClassLoader()` and **delegates** all other methods to the above `OsgiServletContext`

Comment: Thanks! This question is a bit old, I asked it here in case of I misunderstood the spec, before writing the issues in your JIRA :-) I hope to be able to use your v8 soon.

Comment: :) I got notified about this question after it's been edited.